# How to identify the modified content in a pdf file?

Tags: python, java, pdf, metadata, pdf2htmlex

Now I have a pdf file which I see the creation time and the modification time.
Is there a way to know which part (e.g. tables/figures/text) are modified in the metadata?

In other words, how could I identify the difference between the initial pdf file the current one.

I tried PyPDF and Pdf2htmlEX which do not help.

Comment: Has the modification been stored as an incremental update or not? If not, you have no chance unless you also have the original.

Comment: https://www.startpage.com/sp/search?query=pdfdiff&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english